# Líneas de códigos de barras borrosas al rotar con Graphis.Rotatetransform

Tags: c#, windows-forms, código-de-barras

Estoy generando unas etiquetas, con varios códigos de barras.
La estructura la monto a partir de unos controles previamente localizados en un formulario.

```
   psettings.PrinterName = MapPrinters.Printers.GetPrinter(this.form.printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = psettings.PrinterName;
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler((object o, PrintPageEventArgs e) =>
        {
            for (int i = pageCount; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(panel.Width/2,panel.Height/2,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
                //Impresió en vertical
                if (((CheckBox)Controls["chkPrint"]).Checked)
                {
                    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(291, 5, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
                }
                PrintLines(form, e);
                lData.ForEach((x =>
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(GetCellData(x.Text, data.Rows[i], x), x.Font, Brushes.Black, ObtainRectangle(x,0,0,offsetY), Alineament(x));
                }));
                lLabel.ForEach((x =>
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(x.Text, x.Font, Brushes.Black, ObtainRectangle(x, 0, 0, offsetY), Alineament(x));
                }));
                lBarCode.ForEach((x =>
                {
                    if (GenerateBarcode(x.Text, data.Rows[i], x) != null)
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(GenerateBarcode(x.Text, data.Rows[i], x), ObtainRectangle(x, 5, 10,offsetY));
                }));
                if (panel != null)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), new Rectangle(panel.Location.X, panel.Location.Y -offsetY, panel.Width, panel.Height));
                if (pageCount == data.Rows.Count - 1)
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    pageCount++;
                    return;
                }
            }

        });
        
        form.printer.Document = pd;
        try
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(pd.PrinterSettings.ToString());
            if (((CheckBox)Controls["chkPrint"]).Checked)
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("label", 291, 826);
            else
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("label", 826, 291);
            pd.Print();
            lcOK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lcOK = false;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return lcOK;
```

El código de barras lo genero con la librería IronBarCod

```
        private Image GenerateBarcode(string text, DataRow dataRow, TextBox ctrl)
    {
        string toData = text.Replace('[', ' ').Replace(']', ' ').Trim();
        if (dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(toData))
        {
            if (dataRow[toData].ToString().Trim() != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    return BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(dataRow[toData].ToString(), BarcodeEncoding.Code128).ToBitmap();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return new Bitmap(1, 1);
                }
            }
            else return null;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

aunque he probado con BarCodeLib y GenCode128 con idéntico resultado.

El caso es que si imprimo por defecto en modo horizontal, todo funciona perfectamente, el problema es que la impresión puede ser en horizontal y en vertical, para lo que hago un Graphics.rotatetransform(90) y es aquí cuando la etiqueta se imprime correctamente, pero las líneas de los códigos de barras se imprimen un poco sombreadas, lo suficiente como para que el lector ya no las entienda.

¿Podéis echarme una mano por favor?

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo tuve una experiencia similar al rotar una imagen, no sé si te valdrá, pero encontré un patrón para que me rote bien `             image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY);
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema es que yo estoy construyendo el documento a imprimir en el mismo evento.
No dispongo de un objeto Imagen como tal para rotarlo de la forma que me me mencionas.

Comment: Intentaste imprimir en la impresora PDF, y ver si tenías el mismo problema?? porque quizás es un asunto de impresora

Comment: @Yussef, si lo probé y es donde se puede apreciar esa especie de antialising que confunde a la impresora térmica.

Comment: @carallot Igual es bien difícil tu problema. Te puedo comentar que hace muchos años yo tuve un problema similar con una impresora zebra, lo que hice fue imprimir por comandos (ya impresora lo aceptaba) y no enviarle una imagen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que poner:

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

U otro valor, a mi este es el que mejor resultado me dio.

Sin usar esto, obtengo lo siguiente:
(nota: todas las imágenes les hice zoom 500%)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo puse al principio del evento PrintPageEventHandler

Comment: Creía que había probado todos los parámetros, pero no, ese no.
Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente.